# Why am I getting an "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" for an array where the index value at 0 is defined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, object

I am writing a piece of code to accept an array containing several objects with the properties "category", "itemName", and "Onsale" and then reorganize it into an object that takes the items in the "category" property and makes them into properties containing values from the "itemNames" property with an additional ($) added next to the value if the "onSale" property in the object it was listed in was true. After writing and testing the code it kept returning the "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" at line 13 where I was trying to call an the the [i] object in an array. My array is defined at that index value so I am not sure what is going on. I apologize if My code looks amateurish I am new to javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to split up the assignment; for example instead of:

```
myObj = items[i]["category"][0];
```

I wrote:

```
myObj = items[i]["category"][0];
myObj.item[i] = ["category"][0];
```

I tried to switch my initial conditions for my for loop; for example to `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`

I tried inputing a different array such as: `myArray = [1, 2, 3, 5]` but I ended up getting the same error but in a different location

Here is my code:

```
function organizeItems(items) {
  let myObj = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i]["category"][0] in myObj === false) {
      if (items[i]["onSale"] === true) {
        myObj = items[i]["category"][0];
        myObj.items[i]["category"][0] = [];
        myObj.items[i]["category"][0].push(items[i]["itemName"][0] + '($)');
      }
      else {
        myObj = items[i]["category"][0];
        myObj.items[i]["category"][0] = [];
        myObj.items[i]["category"][0].push(items[i]["itemName"][0]);
      }
    }
    else {
      if (items[i]["onSale"] === true) {
        myObj.items[i]["category"][0].push(items[i]["itemName"][0] + '($)');
      }
      else {
        myObj.items[i]["category"][0].push(items[i]["itemName"][0]);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(myObj);
  return myObj;

}
var iten = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var itemData = [
  { category: 'fruit', itemName: 'apple', onSale: false },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'beans', onSale: false },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'corn', onSale: true },
  { category: 'frozen', itemName: 'pizza', onSale: false },
  { category: 'fruit', itemName: 'melon', onSale: true },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'soup', onSale: false },
];

organizeItems(itemData);
```

And here is the error I received:

```bash
/usr/src/app/test/unit_tests_spec.js:19
    myObj.items[i]["category"][0] = [];
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at organizeItems (/usr/src/app/test/unit_tests_spec.js:20:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/test/unit_tests_spec.js:47:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at loader (/usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/babel- register/lib/node.js:154:7)  
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:514:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:480:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: `myObj = items[i]["category"][0]` you're overwriting `myObj` with the first character of the first `item.category` that you encounter. Did you mean to set a property on `myObj`? Secondly you can't access a dynamic key using dot notation so you would need to use bracket notation `myObj[items[i]["category"][0]]`

Comment: see: [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), specifically [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation) and [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)

Comment: can you please describe what is the expected output here? In the initial initialization myobj will get object values.  Not a key value pair, so you should rewrite of you want obj key,value pair.

Comment: @MuthulakshmiM, what I was trying to do was take objects organized in the way itemData was and transfer them to a single object where the item in the category property became the property of the new object containing an array of itemNames' that corresponded with that property.

Comment: @Jay can u pls try below snippet. if it need to change please update your comments.

Comment: @pilchard, I was trying to access an object in the itemData array and from that take value associated with the "category" property and use it as a new property for myObj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved your problem.

**Explain**
items[i]["category"][0]'s value letters first character.
So, If you want put category letters on myObj.
mbObj.items[i]["category"][0] is not correctly syntax.
myObj[items[i]["category"][0]] is correctly.
If you want category's full letter. not first character.
myObj[items[i]["category"]] = []; < this code means => myObj = { [items[i]["category"]] : []}

If you want easy to paste . 
https://bokboot.net/read?id=48&key=44426bed-78e6-49b0-80c1-9d8a13410523

```
function organizeItems(items) {
    let myObj = {}
    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if(items[i]["category"] in myObj === false) {
                if(items[i]["onSale"] === true) {
                    myObj[items[i]["category"]] = [];
                    myObj[items[i]["category"]].push(items[i]["itemName"] + '($)');
                }
                else {
                    myObj[items[i]["category"]] = [];
                    myObj[items[i]["category"]].push(items[i]["itemName"]);
                }
             }
             else {
                 if(items[i]["onSale"] === true) {
                     myObj[items[i]["category"]].push(items[i]["itemName"] + '($)');
                 }
                 else {
                     myObj[items[i]["category"]].push(items[i]["itemName"]);
                 }
             }
}
console.log(myObj);    
return myObj;  
    
}
var iten = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var itemData = [
{ category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'apple', onSale: false },
{ category: 'canned', itemName: 'beans', onSale: false },
{ category: 'canned', itemName: 'corn',  onSale: true  },
{ category: 'frozen', itemName: 'pizza', onSale: false },
{ category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'melon', onSale: true  },
{ category: 'canned', itemName: 'soup',  onSale: false },
 ];

organizeItems(itemData);
```

Comment: Okay, I think I can see what I am doing wrong. I thought that if I only put the property name without the adding an index value that I would make the properties of my new object the same as my old one. If I am understanding you correctly 'myObj[items[i]["category"]] = [];' will refer to the item inside the property not the property itself and that it will create a new property with an empty array without me needing to create the property first.

Answer (score 0):

Updated

```js
     function organizeItems(items) {
          let myObj = {};
          for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if(Object.hasOwn(myObj, `${items[i]["category"]}`)){
            let arrVal = myObj[`${items[i]["category"]}`];
            arrVal.push((items[i]["itemName"]));
            }else{
              myObj[`${items[i]["category"]}`]=[`${items[i]["itemName"]}`];
            }
          }
          console.log(myObj);
          return myObj;
        }
        var itemData = [
          { category: 'fruit', itemName: 'apple', onSale: false },
          { category: 'canned', itemName: 'beans', onSale: false },
          { category: 'canned', itemName: 'corn', onSale: true },
          { category: 'frozen', itemName: 'pizza', onSale: false },
          { category: 'fruit', itemName: 'melon', onSale: true },
          { category: 'canned', itemName: 'soup', onSale: false },
        ];

        organizeItems(itemData);
```

Comment: I think I explained it poorly, sorry. The output I was trying to get looks like this. {
  fruit:  ['apple', 'melon($)'],
  canned: ['beans', 'corn($)', 'soup'],
  frozen: ['pizza']
};

Comment: ryohojins code snippet works but I am still trying to figure out why

Comment: @jay Updated the snippet. I hope it will help.

Comment: I think, I get the gist of what is going on here, though some of the syntax is new to me. I am pretty new to js so I'll have to look it over some more but thanks for the help.

Comment: @jay I hope it gives your expected result. If yes can you mark this answer as a valid one.